# Running a LINQPad query with SQL impersonation

Tags: c#, linqpad

I am trying to perform a SQL query, in LINQPad, with [impersonation](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10090/A-small-C-Class-for-impersonating-a-User) but the impersonating user does not have access to the original user's AppData folder, which causes my `SqlConnection` constructor to throw a `TypeInitializationException`:

```
using (var db = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    // ...
}
```

> The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' threw an exception.

The InnerException here is a `FileNotFoundException` on the actual executable for the LINQPad query:

> C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\LINQPad\ProcessServer5AnyCPUB\LINQPad.UserQuery.exe

Is there some way for me to configure that folder so that LINQPad will try to run with an executable in a location accessible by all user accounts? I have looked at LINQPad's preferences but I couldn't find any place to specify the folder for the `LINQPad.UserQuery.exe`

Comment: Did you check this solution? https://forum.linqpad.net/discussion/761/linqpad-userquery-exe-prevented-from-running-by-group-policy

Comment: A simpler and more robust solution than using impersonation is to use `runas /netonly` to run LINQPad under your own credentials but using another set of credentials for the purpose of remote authentication only. Alternatively, if this is the *only* way to access the server and you want to do this all the time, you can use the Credential Manager to store a credential for `server:1433` instead. This assumes you're impersonating just to log in as a different user in SQL; if you need impersonation for something else this may not apply.

Comment: The SQL server only supports Windows Authentication and the user account that has access to it does not have access to all of the other things needed to run my script (like for example nuget packages). I have to run LINQPad as my own user in order to be able to compile but I need impersonation in order to connect to the DB.

Comment: Yeah, it sounds like `runas /netonly` and/or Credential Manager would be exactly appropriate in this case, assuming you don't need remote authentication with your own credentials at any point (for the NuGet packages, for example). Full impersonation is very fragile in that a lot of functions simply don't support it, resulting in rather unpredictable results. Network-only credentials don't have this problem.

Comment: @tanathos the workaround from the LINQPad forums does not work for me. I tried copying `LINQPad.UserQuery.exe` into my LINQPad installation directory but now the inner exception from my SQL script has changed to:
Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))

Comment: @JeroenMostert I cannot use the Credential Manager either as Windows credentials are disabled by group policy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this after posting a question in the LINQPad user forum ([link](https://forum.linqpad.net/discussion/1909/configuring-the-location-of-linqpad-userquery-exe/)). The key came from a link suggested by Joe Albahari himself:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/90e313c6-bf2f-45ac-a595-a7b6c4aae7e1/windowsidentityimpersonate-throws-catastrophic-failure-exception-from-hresult-0x8000ffff

I moved the impersonation call so that, instead of wrapping around the `SqlConnection` and the commands associated with it, it now wraps only around my `db.Open()` statement. This is because an impersonated `SqlConnection` constructor tries to read various configs from places it might not have access to.

I am still debating with myself whether this can cause problems if a pre-opened connection is available from the connection pool but, for the purposes of my application, I don't have that problem.